# Trigger event handler with custom event object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Is it possible to trigger an event on some object with a custom event object?
i.e.

```
$('#Element1').click(function(event){
    console.log('Element1 clicked', event);
}

$('#Element2').click(function(event)
{ //handle click on one element

  //optionally modify the event object
  event.target=Something;
  
  //Trigger the event handler(s) on some other element using modified event object
  $('#Element1').click(event);
});
```

A bit of background:

In my instance `Element2` is an almost identical clone of `Element1` but with different position. When `Element2` is clicked that click should be forwarded to `Element1`.

I already have code to identify the correct child of `Element1` according to which child of `Element2` was clicked but the click event handler on the child of element 1 requires the `pageX` and `pageY` properties to be set correctly and `.click()` omits these properties entirely.

It does **not** suffice in my example to do a deep clone and include the event handlers because the target property is incorrectly set.

One workaround in my instance would be for the cloned element to retain a reference to the original element (and for every child) and the handler to check for that reference, however, I would prefer a solution where the handler has no knowledge of the cloning process - not least because there are a LOT of handlers to modify!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not understand well your background logic, but you can try with `trigger` from jQuery. You can trigger event reusing the event object:

```
$('#Element1').click(function(event){
    console.log('Element1 clicked with changed event: ' + event.something);
});

$('#Element2').click(function(event){ 

    event.something = "Something";

    $('#Element1').trigger(event);
});
```

Comment: I should have read the documentation properly - I hadn't spotted the 2nd overload of the trigger function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#trigger-event-extraParameters) it accepts an event object as the argument

```
$('#Element1').trigger(event);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WZMwg/)